# Swift 3 - Index out of range - Details/More Info

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am creating a project in Swift 3 and I keep getting a "Fatal Error: Index out of range" error. I understand what the error is telling me, however I have a large number of arrays that could be causing the problem. It is hard for me to pinpoint the issue since it occurs when I call a function, which calls other functions which manipulate multiple arrays. I was wondering if there was any way I can view which line of code or which array is specifically causing the out of range error? When the error occurs, xCode switches to display a kind of "debug" looking screen with a wall of text however I can not see any information about what is specifically causing the issue.

I can't seem to view any sort of debug information that could help me, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to add exception breakpoint ?? to track exception

Answer (score 1):

you can trace the method which cause crashing, debug navigator which shows sequence of function (recently called function on Top) probably the top most function where your app crash

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put log of all arrays and object at index in loop. array as obj as! [typeOfObj]. You'll see last object till it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global breakpoint to locate the error code。